# Smart argument for limit of side difference in a triangle

Tags: limits, triangles, plane-geometry

[image]

Answer is (B). Of course, we may express $s$ in terms of $r$ using cosine law and take the limit and show the limit is $\cos(70)<1$. But I don't think that this method is intended because if it were they could have just asked for the exact value of the limit. I wonder if there is a geometric argument that allows us to see this immediately.

Comment: $\cos(70^\circ)$?

Comment: @saulspatz thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend $r$ and make the extension equal to $s$. You will get a small triangle with sides $1, s-r, x$ and angle between sides $1$ and $s-r$ equal to $70°$. Obviously $s-r < 1$ because it's opposite to a smaller angle (we have isosceles triangle with sides $s, s, x$ so the base angles are equal).

Comment: Very good set-up! It leads to exact answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a picture for the geometric limit:

[image: Geometric limit of the difference of two sides of a triangle when a side and one angle adjacent to it remain constant]

The points $A$, $O$, the length of $AO=1$, and the half-line where $X$ moves on are fixed. We construct $B$ as in the picture, $BO\perp OX$, $AB\|OX$, and the angle in $O$ in $\Delta AOB$ has the measure $20^\circ$.
Let $X$ be the point going to the infinity, and for each fixed position of $X$, let $Y$ (depending on $X$) be the intersection of $AX$ and $OB$.

Then we have a sandwich for $XY-OX$, 
$$
0\le\boxed{\  XY-OX\ }=\frac{XY^2-OX^2}{XY+OX}=\frac{OY^2}{XY+OX}
\le \frac{OB^2}{XY+OX}\to 0\ ,$$
so 
$$
\begin{aligned}
s-r &=AX-OX
\\
&=SY +(YX-OX)
\\
&\to AB+0 =AB
\\
&=\sin 20^\circ\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Of course, it is easy to use the Theorem of Pythagoras to get the formula for $s$ in terms of $r$, explicitly $s^2=r^2-2r\cos 110^\circ +1 =r^2+2r\sin 20^\circ +1$, then compute (as above geometrically) the limit of $s-r$ as the limit of $(s^2-r^2)/(s+r)$. The denominator $s+r$ is "working" like $2r$, and the numerator can be expressed as above, we divide by brute force with $2r$, get the same limit.